# Address one known person and multiple unknown people in a letter

Tags: letter-writing, salutations

I am submitting my CV to a company for the purposes of an internship application, I know the name of the the person who manages the interns, but he has told me that he will pass my CV onto the rest of the company for consideration of permanent employment.

How would I address the intern manager and anyone else who reads the CV.

Dear James or Sir/Madam

Comment: Is the intern manager refering you? i.e, final word on your internship may not be his.                                       if yes, then, why not follow the formal approach-Dear Sir/madam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid a direct salutation by going with something more like:

```
Greetings,

<letter body>
```

I think it'd sound better than:

```
Dear James and whoever else it may concern,
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options I would consider;

Firstly, is it likely that your covering letter and C.V. will be appropriate and relevant for both your internship application, and permanent employment? If not, then simply include another CV and covering letter for James to distribute to colleagues - in which case, you can use Dear Sir/madam, or to who it may concern on that version.

If the same covering letter and C.V. would be relevant for both types of position,
I would personally still address it just to James, therefore 'Dear James' and then in the covering letter you might add a small thank you or mention for passing it to other staff for consideration of permanent employment which they will read. If he is personally sending it to other staff members, they may reasonably expect it to have just been addressed to him anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"Dear Sir/Madam" would be just fine. Keep only one copy of CV and covering letter.

Your covering letter should encompass the internship application and consideration of permanent employment.